# Unable to connect to wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration

I have a brand new ASUS Wireless Router RT-N65U.

On it, I set up two different wireless networks. One uses a 2.4 Ghz bandwidth and the other is using a 5 Ghz bandwidth. Their broadcast names are different but their password are identicals.

My trouble is that, all my Apple devices (1 IPhone, I MacBook Pro, 1 IPad) are able to connect to it without trouble. My two Windows laptop cannot. I can see only one out of two network (I see the 5G) and when I try and connect to it, Windows complains that he cannot perform the operation.

It is driving me nuts, any idea what might go wrong here ?

Comment: Your card might not be compatible with 5 ghz signals. Try getting rid of the 5 and leave only the 2.5 and disconnect all devices and let windows connect first

Comment: This happens to me a lot when dealing with apple devices in the same network as windows. They are HOGS, it drives me nuts. I have to reboot the router so i can connect my windows and android devices. So also reboot the router

Comment: I disabled my 5G network but I cannot see my 2G broadcasted. Everything worked yesterday, I tried to connect my GF Windows laptop on the wireless and everything started to fail. I reseted my router a few time to restart clean but I can't manage to broadcast my 2G network... I don't get it... I double checked, my 2G is not hidden.

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Finally "solved" it. I unplugged my router and let it unplugged while I was having my supper. About 1 hour later I switched it on again and I could connect properly on my 5G network. Both my Windows laptops were compatible with 5G but one needed a driver update. I still couldn't manage to broadcast my 2G network tho. I'll keep an eye on this router, the behavior seems really odd to me. Thanks for your help !